# Rsync: Exclude directory contents, but include directory

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I know that a directory can be excluded with `--exclude` like this:

`rsync -avz --exclude=dir/to/skip /my/source/path /my/backup/path`

This will omit the directory `dir/to/skip`

However I want to **copy the directory itself but not the contents** | Is there a one-liner with rsync to accomplish this?

Essentially, **include** `dir/to/skip` but **exclude** `dir/to/skip/*`

> NOTE: I did search for this question. I found a lot of similar posts but not exactly this. Apologies if there is a dupe already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--exclude` option takes a `PATTERN`, which means you just should just be able to do this:

```
rsync -avz --exclude='dir/to/skip/*' /my/source/path /my/backup/path
```

Note that the `PATTERN` is quoted to prevent the shell from doing glob expansion on it.

Since `dir/to/skip` doesn't match the pattern `dir/to/skip/*`, it will be included.

Here's an example to show that it works:

```
> mkdir -p a/{1,2,3}
> find a -type d -exec touch {}/file \;
> tree --charset ascii a
a
|-- 1
|   `-- file
|-- 2
|   `-- file
|-- 3
|   `-- file
`-- file

3 directories, 4 files


> rsync -r --exclude='/2/*' a/ b/
> tree --charset ascii b
b
|-- 1
|   `-- file
|-- 2
|-- 3
|   `-- file
`-- file

3 directories, 3 files
```

It is important to note that the leading `/` in the above `PATTERN` represents the root of the source directory, *not* the filesystem root. This is explained in the `rsync` man page. If you omit the leading slash, `rsync` will attempt to match the `PATTERN` from the *end* of each path. This could lead to excluding files unexpectedly. For example, suppose I have a directory `a/3/2/` which contains a bunch of files that I *do* want to transfer. If I omit the leading `/` and do:

```
rsync -r --exclude='2/*' a/ b/
```

then the `PATTERN` will match both `a/2/*` and `a/3/2/*`, which is not what I wanted.

Comment: Yep, and the `--filter` option also provides a number of fine-grained controls as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
rsync -avz --include=src/dir/to/skip --exclude=src/dir/to/skip/* src_dir dest_dir
```

`--include=src/dir/to/skip` includes the directory. `--exclude=src/dir/to/skip/*` excludes everything under the directory.

In general, a single `rsync` command can contain many such `--include` and `--exclude` filter rules.  Their order is important: they are processed in the order they appear on the command line and the *first* matching rule is the one that is acted on.  Subsequent rules are ignored.

Comment: when intending to keep some files inside the directory, **the order of `--include` and `--exclude` is important**: first specify the include(s), *then* the exclude. example: `rsync -avh --include='subdir/x' --exclude='subdir/*' src_dir dest_dir` will keep from `subdir/` only `subdir/x`, and will not rsync anything else inside `subdir/`.

Comment: @Abdull Yes, good point.  I added a paragraph to the answer to mention the importance of rule order.